# Concurrent Authentication request in API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We are getting error while performing Concurrent authentication request to /token. What are the configuration we are supposed to do to solve this. the number of user we are getting this error is 150 users and plus.

Comment: Can you specify the oAuth grant type, number of users in the system, scope which you are trying?

Comment: it is client credentials